# How to avoid print of pressed button by KeyboardHookCallback method in .net?

Tags: .net

I have the following method, which should replace pressed button "I" by the text "Hello world".

The command `return (IntPtr)1` should avoid print "I" on the screen. It works alone, however, when I do several operations before it, the button "I" is printed out before the algorithm will get to `return (IntPtr)1`.

```
        private static IntPtr KeyboardHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                Keys key = (Keys)vkCode;

                if (IsSSMSActive())
                {
                    if (!isSendingKeys)
                    {
                        if (key == Keys.I)
                        {
                            SendKeys.Flush();
                            isSendingKeys = true;
                            string text = "Hello world";
                            foreach (char c in text)
                            {
                                SendKeys.Send(c.ToString());
                                Thread.Sleep(200); // Spomalenie odosielania znaku na 200 milisekúnd
                            }
                            isSendingKeys = false;
                            return (IntPtr)1;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            return CallNextHookEx(hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
```